# Programmatically update Bibdesk file locations

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk

I moved the directory containing my PDF files at some point and now all BibDesk references to the local PDF copies are showing `localhost:missing`.

Is there a way to go in to the .bib file and rewrite the Bdsk-File-1 fields to point to the new directory?

Comment: You can either move the directory back to the original location, or move your .bib file to the same relative path as when you moved it. For example, if you had `~/my.bib`and `~/PDF`, and now have `~/my.bib` and `/Volumes/BigDisk/PDF`, move the .bib file to `/Volumes/BigDisk/my.bib`. Open the file and if the links are working, save the file to update them. After that, you should be able to move the .bib file elsewhere, but save it after doing so.

Comment: So after a bit more digging, it seems like when I moved my refs to iCloud Documents (far from trouble free in general), the relative paths were lost. For example, one file seems to be in `../../Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/.Trash/refs/Nuseibeh/Weaving Together Requirements and Architectures .pdf`

Moral of the story: be careful with iCloud document storage.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how iCloud Documents works, and I'm frankly a bit scared of it. BibDesk should work reasonably well with DropBox, based on feedback I've seen, but I realize that doesn't help you at present. BibDesk tracks files via a MacOS alias, plus absolute and relative paths, but it's a tricky business to get right, and predates things like iCloud Documents and even DropBox.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the `.bib` file in TextEdit and used find/replace to change

```
Local-Url = {originalPATHtoFOLDER/
```

to

```
Local-Url = {newPATHtoFOLDER/
```

After the slash the actual pdf file followed by `}` is stored in the `.bib` file entry.

This worked for me.